# Send message to specific websocket client using nodejs

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, ws

I'm trying to implement a chat application (the client is an android app). Currently I'm using the ws package for the websocket, and I'm planning on storing the connection in an object using the user's id as the key for implementing sending to a specific client.

However I'm wondering if  it has any negative impact because I'm storing that object globally in the memory. Would this be a good approach?

The alternative that I found is switching the lib to socket.io and using rooms. This implementation seems a bit more straightforward and I think it would help me if I'll want to implement groups in the future. However, I'll have to refactor a bit of the code to use it.

I'm open to other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Rooms are the way go. It allows you to use things like socket.io redis as well so you can use your socket server in a cluster mode.

When creating a room you can choose set it up in such a way that its a group room OR private. Rooms are just based off the name so a private room might be userID1 + userID2 or what ever to make it unique to just those two users ( you can also pass validation via JWT to ensure people have access )